# Trying to find a sewing pattern or style name for this style of dess

Tags: sewing, style-identification

[image: Retro dress]

Hello I am trying to find a sewing pattern that has the same type of style for the chest area of this dress or just the name of the style so that I have something to go on. I'm not too worried about the skirt just the chest.
Any help would be greatly appriciated.

Comment: Are you looking for the bunched cross section or the separate bust panel? What about the chest area, specifically?

Comment: I suggest searching by image, where you upload this specific pic and looking for similar images to see what they are called... I'm sure you will find what you need. Good Luck.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A company that makes them, Lindy Bop, calls them their "[Ophelia](https://www.lindybopusa.com/ophelia-dark-red.html)" style dress and they have a similar one that's called "[Sloane](https://www.lindybopusa.com/sloane-mustard-cotton-swing-dress.html)". It's a vintage style from the 50s - "Rockabilly swing".

The description of the bodice they use in various places include:

> - Sweetheart neckline with ruched satin inset
> - a sweetheart neckline with turquoise ruched bust panel.
> - sweetheart neckline with contrasting crossover ruched bust panel

Google search returns a fair number of similar dresses when you search for "Rockabilly dress"... including the image that you posted, which is on [a site here](http://rockabillyclothing50s.com/product/acevog-womens-1950s-v-neck-vintage-cut-out-retro-party-cocktail-swing-dresses/) where they describe it as "ACEVOG Women’s 1950s V Neck Vintage Cut Out Retro Party Cocktail Swing Dresses"

Other than that, I'm not sure there's a specific name for the style.

Comment: Looks like "sweetheart neckline" and "ruched [panel]" may be the keywords to look for. Nice find!